# Struggling to understand how to loop over a list

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm currently developing a POS till system as a university assignment and I'm completely stumped on a for loop that I need to implement to save any data that gets added to the system by the end user. The save() function is meant to save any data put into the program to 1 of 2 .txt files (stock or till).

I've currently built the save function for each of the different instance variables but when it runs through the save() method it'll only run once (obviously) and I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement a sample for loop as a solution.

Here's my current progress:

```
public void save() throws IOException {
    // IMPLEMENTATION
    PrintWriter outfileStock = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(SHOP_STOCK_DATA_FILE));
    outfileStock.println(barcode);
    outfileStock.println(cost);
    outfileStock.println(quantity);

    outfileStock.close();

    PrintWriter outfileTill = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(SHOP_TILL_DATA_FILE));
    outfileTill.println();
    outfileTill.println();
    outfileTill.println();

    outfileTill.close();
}
```

The sample for loop we've been given (from a worksheet that lead up to this assignment is this:

```
public void save(String fileName) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    outfile.println(type);
    outfile.println(face);
    outfile.println(hair);
    outfile.println(powerPoints);
    outfile.println(loot.size());
    for (Treasure treasure : loot) {
        outfile.println(treasure.getName());
        outfile.println(treasure.getValue());
    }
    outfile.close();
```

While I'm not asking for the code to be written for me, it would be great if somebody to explain how the

```
for (Treasure treasure : loot) {
    outfile.println(treasure.getName());
    outfile.println(treasure.getValue());
}
```

loop works. I can provide some more info if needed, fairly new to Java so not sure how much is needed to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loot` is an `ArrayList` that contains `Treasure` *objects*.

```
for (Treasure treasure : loot) {
    outfile.println(treasure.getName());
    outfile.println(treasure.getValue());
}
```

*loops over each one of the* `Treasure` objects (each one of which are temporarily assigned to `treasure`) by this line of code:

```
for (Treasure treasure : loot) {
```

which means (for every `Treasure` object in `loot` which you call `treasure`)

and gets (for each) their `name` (`treasure.getName()`) and their values (`treasure.getValue()`).

```
:
```

stands for the `enhanced for-loop` which was introduced in `Java SE 5.0`. See more info here:

```
https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with
```

Basically, instead of

```
for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Element: " + array[i]);
}
```

you can now do

```
for (String element : array) {
    System.out.println("Element: " + element);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

loot seems to be a List of some sort. What the for loop will do is take each element of this list and return them to you as a single object called treasure. when you get this element back you can treat is as a normal Treasure object. In your case it seems to be writing the treasure name and value to a file.

[For each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Loot is initialised as an ArrayList (I think!) here:
 `private ArrayList<Treasure> loot;`

and then referenced here: `loot = new ArrayList<Treasure>();`

Does that offer any further explanation or change your answer at all?

Thanks for your response!

Comment: It doesn't change the answer. ArrayList implements the List interface.

Comment: Thanks serge! Would you mind telling me what `:` stands for in java? Googled around a bit and can't seem to find a solid answer. Is it as simple as `=`?

Comment: In this case you could read it as "in". So for each treasure in loot.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic Java. The variable loot is something that can be iterated over. It's either an array or one of the container classes like ArrayList. It contains Treasure objects.

For each element in the loot array, those two lines of code are executed.

Answer (score 0):

loot is a `List`. Therefore using this [enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) it fetch the each element in each iteration and assign it to the `treasure` variable. But here you don't have access to the previous element of the list in a given time. If you use other for loop `for(int x=0; x < size ; x++ )` in each iteration you can access previous or next element by coding `loot.get(x-1) or loot.get(x+1). Therefore it depends on your requirement.